# Does a binoid contain an empty word?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, semigroups, monoid

$A$ is a finite alphabet. $A^*$ is the set of finite words or the free monoid generated by A.

$A^w$ is the set of infinite words generated by A. Denote $A^\infty=A^*\bigcup A^w$.

$X$ is a set of $A^\infty$. Denote $X_{*}=X\bigcap A^*$, $X_w=X\bigcap A^w$.

A binoid over $A$ is a subset $M$ of $A^\infty$ such that
$$M_* M\subseteq M,\quad (M_*)^w\subseteq M.$$
The product of two elements is just using concatenation to put them together.

---

The notation and definition above quote from Algebraic Combinatorics on Words (2002), which is written by M.Lothaire.

It seems that if M is a binoid, $M_*$ must be a  subsemigroup of $A^*$. But the book also mentioned that such $M_*$ is also a submonoid of $A^*$.

My question is how to ensure the empty word or so-called unit belongs to $M_*$, such that $M_*$ is not only a subsemigroup, but also a submonoid of $A^*$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how it does. If you take $M = A^{\omega}-\{\text{emptyword}\}$, then it would seem to me that $M$ is a binoid.

Comment: @ Arturo Magidin :I agree that $M=A^ω−${emptyword}.So I don't konw how $M_*$ comes to be submonoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lothaire goes on to define, for $X\subseteq A^\infty$, $X^\infty\triangleq X_*^\infty\cup(X_*)^*X_\omega=X_*\,^*\cup X_*\,^\omega\cup(X_*)^*X_\omega$ and to say that $M\subseteq A^\infty$ is a binoid iff $M^\infty=M$. Clearly $\varepsilon\in X_*\,^*\subseteq X^\infty$ for all $X\subseteq A^\infty$, so he really does expect a binoid to contain $\varepsilon$ (the empty word).

Equally clearly, $M^\infty=M$ does not follow from $M_*M\subseteq M$ and $(M_*)^\omega\subseteq M$: let $M=\{a^\omega\}$ for some $a\in A$, and note that $M_*=\varnothing$, whence $M_*M=(M_*)^\omega=\varnothing\subseteq M$. Indeed, any non-empty $M\subseteq A^\omega$ would work for the same reason, and Arturo’s example, $M=A^+\cup A^\omega$, also works: $M_*M=A^+(A^+\cup A^\omega)=AA^+\cup A^\omega$ and $(M_*)^\omega=(A^+)^\omega=A^\omega$ are plainly subsets of $M$.

It appears to me that the simplest way to salvage the definition is to require that $M_*M=M$ and $(M_*)^\omega\subseteq M$, thereby forcing $\varepsilon$ to belong to $M_*$; the weaker requirement in the book may simply be a typo.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott:As what you explained above,the reason for why $ε$ belongs to M is $M^\infty =M$,which implies $M_* ^*$⊆M.Yes?If I fix the definition as $M_* M=M$,I can just make sure the iff condition does hold.But it seems that I still can't get $ε$ belong to M,if I just follow the definition of binoid which is fixed as above.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott:And the book implied that $M_*$ is a submonoid a little earlier than the iff condition appears.

Comment: @Andylang: I agree: the conditions $M_* M\subseteq M$ and $(M_*)^\omega\subseteq M$ don’t imply that $\varepsilon\in M$. But replacing $M_* M\subseteq M$ with $M_* M=M$ does, and also implies that $M^\infty=M$, which is pretty clearly what he really wants.

Comment: @  Brian M. Scott: Finally,I completely get your point and agree with you.I think I have no problem now.Thank you for your guiding!